# Inconsistent ASP.NET WebHooks

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, asp.net-webhooks

I'm trying to set up an Azure WebJob to use a custom WebHook to push data to a Web App (which will then push it on to clients using SignalR). The WebJob is run on a schedule (it polls another service to check if there's any new data).

I've based it on this [MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/30/sending-asp-net-webhooks-from-azure-webjobs/), and on the [CustomSender.WebJob](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/tree/dev/samples/CustomSender.WebJob) and [CustomReceiver](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/tree/dev/samples/CustomReceiver) sample projects from MS.

The system is live on Azure, and mostly works, but it's not consistent. The job runs every three minutes and always sends the WebHook - at least it always logs this trace message, which I think means it's sending the WebHook:

```
Configuring 'DataflowWebHookSender' with a total of 3 attempt(s) of sending WebHooks.
```

However the WebHookHandler doesn't always receive the WebHook. Sometimes I get the trace message below, sometimes nothing:

```
Processing incoming WebHook request with receiver 'custom' and id ''.
```

While there are obviously quite a few places where there could be a problem, the fact that it works intermittently makes me think that the code and config are all OK, and I'm a bit stuck as to why the handler isn't receiving the WebHooks more consistently. Am I wrong to expect WebHooks to work all the time?

---

**Azure Log Stream extract**

```
2017-08-18T08:56:40  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2017-08-18T08:57:01  PID[15308] Information Configuring 'DataflowWebHookSender' with a total of 3 attempt(s) of sending WebHooks.
2017-08-18T08:58:40  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2017-08-18T08:59:40  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2017-08-18T09:00:02  PID[16092] Information Configuring 'DataflowWebHookSender' with a total of 3 attempt(s) of sending WebHooks.
2017-08-18T09:00:13  PID[15256] Information Registered 'IWebHookReceiver' instances with the following names: custom.
2017-08-18T09:00:13  PID[15256] Information Processing incoming WebHook request with receiver 'custom' and id ''.
2017-08-18T09:00:14  PID[15256] Information Registered configuration setting 'Custom' for ID '''.
2017-08-18T09:01:40  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2017-08-18T09:02:40  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2017-08-18T09:03:01  PID[15092] Information Configuring 'DataflowWebHookSender' with a total of 3 attempt(s) of sending WebHooks.
2017-08-18T09:04:40  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2017-08-18T09:05:40  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2017-08-18T09:06:00  PID[12892] Information Configuring 'DataflowWebHookSender' with a total of 3 attempt(s) of sending WebHooks.
2017-08-18T09:07:40  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuring message just says that the sender is initializing with the default policy of retrying. Things to looks for in the logs:

1) Is the sender generating a webhook?
2) Is the receiver receiving the webhook?
3) can you see any errors or retries in transmission of the webhook?

Henrik

Comment: Thanks Henrik. I've added an extract from the Azure Log Stream to the question. I've got a ConsoleTraceListener set up for both the web job and the web app, but that's all I'm getting - do I need to look somewhere else?